# NetLogo Check values of linked turtles in own network

Tags: netlogo

I created a network of turtles linked by bidirectional links

```
ask turtles [              
     create-links-with other turtles in-radius 1 ]
```

Each turtle has two parameters alpha and beta.

Now, I want to ask each turtle to set alpha = 1 if and only if AT LEAST ONE turtle linked to him has beta = 1. Otherwise, I want to ask each turtle to set alpha = 0 if and only if ALL turtles linked to him has beta = 0.

Answer (score 1):

The primitive `all?` checks if all members of an agentset satisfy some condition. And a suitable agentset is `link-neighbors`, which is the linked turtles.

```
ask turtles
[ set alpha ifelse-value (all? link-neighbors [beta = 0]) [0] [1]
]
```

Note that, if the links aren't actually being used for anything, you can do this without creating links with:

```
ask turtles
[ set alpha ifelse-value (all? other turtles in-radius 1 [beta = 0]) [0] [1]
]
```

Comment: Thank you, could you explain to me the meaning of [0] and [1] at the end?

Comment: Have a look at the NetLogo documentation for the `ifelse-value` primitive. There are three arguments, the test, then the value for if the test is true, then the value for if the test is false. So the 0 and 1 are the values to return .